# SliderInput and SelectInput in Shiny App not working

Tags: r, shiny, dataset, dashboard

Can someone please help me in solving following Shiny App query of sliderinput and selectinput on mtcars dataset.
I shall be extremely grateful.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

## ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("mtcars table"),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(

                column(width = 5,
                       selectInput(inputId = "gear",
                                   label = "gear:",
                                   choices = c("All",
                                               unique(as.character(mtcars$gear))))),

                column(width = 10,
                       sliderInput(inputId = "am",
                                   label = "am:",
                                   min = 0,
                                   max = 1,
                                   value = c(0,1),
                                   step = 1)),


                column(width = 10,
                       sliderInput(inputId = "hp",
                                   label = "hp:",
                                   min = 52,
                                   max = 335,
                                   value = c(52,335),
                                   step = 1)

                )),

              mainPanel ( 
                DT::dataTableOutput("table"))))
```

## server

```
server<-function(input, output) {

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
data <- mtcars

ifelse(test = input$gear != 'All', yes =data<- data[data$gear == input$gear,], 0)
data<-data[data$am == input$am,] 
data<-data[data$hp==input$hp,]

data
}))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny);
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("mtcars table"), sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel(

  column(width = 5,
         selectInput(inputId = "gear",
                     label = "gear:",
                     choices = c("All" = 0,
                                 unique(as.character(mtcars$gear))))),

  column(width = 10,
         selectInput(inputId = "am",
                     label = "am:",
                     choices = unique(as.character(mtcars$am)))),


  column(width = 10,
         sliderInput(inputId = "hp",
                     label = "hp:",
                     min = 52,
                     max = 335,
                     value = c(52,335),
                     step = 1)

  )),

  mainPanel ( 
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"))))


server<-function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({ 

  data <- mtcars

  if(input$gear != 0){
    data<-data[data$gear == input$gear, ]
  }
  data<-data[data$am %in%  input$am,] 
  data<-data[data$hp >= input$hp[[1]] & data$hp <= input$hp[[2]],]


  data
  }))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aleksandr, your a genius mate :)

Comment: Hi Aleksanadr, can you please help me with this? I'm stuck on it since last 2 days.        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961740/problem-with-selecting-variables-columns-using-radiobuttons-and-selectinput-in-s