# problem with selecting variables/columns using radioButtons and selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, datatables, shiny, dashboard

I'm unable to select/unselect different columns of mtcars dataset using both radioButtons and selectInput function in Shiny.
Can someone please help me out as i'm stuck on it since last 2 days. 
I shall be extremely grateful.

Regards

```
data(mtcars)
#Ui
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout( 
 sidebarPanel(
  column(width = 10,
         radioButtons(inputId="variables", label="Select variables:",
                      choices = c("All","mpg","cyl","disp"),
                      selected = "All", inline = TRUE )),

  column(width = 10,
         selectInput(inputId = "level", label = "Choose Variables to 
                     display", multiple = TRUE, choices =  names(mtcars)[4:11]))),


mainPanel ( 
  h2("mtcars Dashboard"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"))))


#server
server<-function(input, output) {

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filter='top', editable = TRUE, caption = 'mtcars',
                                                {  

                                    data <- mtcars
                                    data<-data[,input$variables,drop=FALSE]

                                      column = names(mtcars)
                                      if (!is.null(input$level)) {
                                          column = input$level  }

                                       data

                                                })) }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `Error in DT::datatable: unused argument (editable = TRUE)` you need to remove `editable` from datatable. Also you need to handle `All` in different way as there is no column called 'All'

Comment: Suliman can you please update my query if possible

Comment: How you plan to use radioButtons and selectInput in the same query.

Comment: you can use some other function, the purpose is to have two different functions for selecting/ unselecting columns

Comment: thanks a lot, can both the functions be applied on 1 single table? i don't want 2 separate tables.  pls guide. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data(mtcars)
#Ui
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout( 
  sidebarPanel(
      column(width = 10,
      radioButtons(inputId="variables", label="Select variables:",
      choices = c("All","mpg","cyl","disp"),
      selected = "All", inline = TRUE )),
      column(width = 10,
      selectInput(inputId = "level", label = "Choose Variables to 
      display", multiple = TRUE, choices =  names(mtcars)[4:11]))),
      mainPanel ( 
      h2("mtcars Dashboard"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
  ))

#server
server<-function(input, output, session) {
  data <- mtcars
  tbl <- reactive({
    if(input$variables=='All'){
      data
    }else{
      data[,c(input$variables,input$level),drop=FALSE]
    }
  })
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filter='top', caption='mtcars', tbl()))  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is what I understand from your requirements, I hope it what you are looking for. Always try to avoid calculations inside render*.

Comment: thanks a lot, can both the functions be applied on 1 single table? i don't want 2 separate table. Regards

Comment: You're most welcome. This what I meant by what is your plan "scenario", do you have two sets of column names and you want to combine them before selecting/deselecting from a table OR radioButton will work before/after selectInput. Shortly what will happen if User select column names from both radioButtons and selectInput.

Comment: @Sid a naive approach to combine radioButtons and selectInput in one table , you can try `data[,c(input$variables,input$level),drop=FALSE]` in tbl1 reactive and remove tbl2 reactive and output.

Comment: Thank you so much Suliman, its so very nice of you. Stay in touch :)